# how to read time from file and perform minus operation on hours using powershell

Tags: powershell, math, datetime-format

I have created a text file that contains id and time[24hr format] that is going to trigger one operation at the mentioned time.

[image]

I want to read both the values and minus 2 hrs from mentioned hr.

I tried, but I am not sure how to read input as time format(24hr notation HH:MM) and  minus 2 hrs from that and also the scenario like 01:30 - 2hr = 23.30 (previous date)

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\wamp64\www\schedule_daily_task.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $fields = $line -split '\s+'
    $id = $fields[0]
    $time = $fields[1] 

    #code here to change the format of $time to time format and perform minus oper 
    #01:30 - 2hr = 23.30 (previous date)
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date and time arithmetics, use .Net's [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) class. It has method `AddHours()` which, when passed negative values, subtracts hours. Calculating new datetime to yesterday is quite straight-forward. Like so,

```
# First, let's get today's date with specific time and minute
$hh = ($fields[1] -split ':')[0]
$mm = ($fields[1] -split ':')[1] 
$dd = get-date -date $(get-date).date -hour $hh -minute $mm

# Add -2 hours
$dd.AddHours(-2)
```

Comment: I am able to get the output but with the error : Get-Date : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Minute'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Date],

Answer (score 0):

I would use `switch -Regex -File` for this to read the file line-by-line and get the values from the lines you are after using regex.
Advantage is that this is crazy fast aswell.

```
$result = switch -regex -File 'C:\wamp64\www\schedule_daily_task.txt' {
    '^(\d+)\s+(\d{2}:\d{2})' { 
        $id = $Matches[1]
        $h, $m = $Matches[2] -split ':'
        $time = '{0:HH:mm}' -f (Get-Date -Hour $h -Minute $m -Second 0).AddHours(-2)
        # output the id and updated time
        "$id $time"
     }
     default { 
        # output any other line you may have in the file. You can of course 
        # also ignore these if they are unwanted in the output. In that case
        # simply comment out this whole 'default' block
        $_ 
     }
}


# output to (new) file and because of '-PassThru' also on screen
$result | Set-Content -Path 'C:\wamp64\www\schedule_daily_task_minus_2.txt' -PassThru
```

Example input file:

```
2603961 01:30
1234567 11:59
9876543 23:30
```

Example output file:

```
2603961 23:30
1234567 09:59
9876543 21:30
```